# Azure permissions to let someone access DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I hired a contractor to work on a web service that uses DocumentDB to store our data. I need the contract to be able to login to Azure and access DocumentDB, but I do not want him playing with major things like users and my subscription. I also do not want him scaling anything up or down.

How do I add him as a user and let him access DocumentDB?

Comment: Basically you would want this person to manage the data in DocumentDB account and not change anything else. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If he needs to manage the docdb resource in the Azure portal, you can [give him reader or contributor rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure) on the invididual resource or on the resource group that contains the documentdb resource. By making him contributor (in case he needs to change things), you ensure that he cannot change any user permissions. Readers obviously cannot change anything.

If you require more complex permissions, you could consider using another [built in role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-built-in-roles) or even creating [a custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles).

In case he just needs to write an application that accesses the DocDB contents, all you have to give him is a connection string and no portal access at all.